# CSS depends on result PHP if-statement

Tags: php, css

I wrote a little script where an item should be **bold** whenever a certain value is set to 0.  But I have the feeling I'm repeating myself... Is there a way to avoid this repeat?

```
$output .= '<td>';
if ('0' == $value['treated']) {
    $output .= '<b>';
}
$output .= $value['from'];
$output .= substr($value['message'], 20);
if ('0' == $value['treated']) {
     $output .= '</b>';
}
$output .= '</td>';
```

Comment: Maybe you should checkout DOMDocument.

Answer (score 5):

You could set a class instead?

```
$output .= '<td' . ('0' == $value['treated'] ? ' class="bold"' : '') . '>';
$output .= $value['from'];
$output .= substr($value['message'], 20);
$output .= '</td>';
```

All you would then need to do is add

```
.bold { font-weight: bold; }
```

to your css file

Answer (score 1):

```
$output = $value['from'] . substr($value['message'], 20);

if ('0' == $value['treated']) {
    $output = "<b>$output</b>";
}

$output = "<td>$output</td>";
```

Comment: Won't I get issues when using `$output` in both cases? Won't it be overwritten?

Comment: Yes, it will be overwritten. But it's not an issue. IMO, consecutively wrapping your output in the necessary tags is a lot easier than cobbling together tags in a sequential way as you are doing.

Comment: True that! And why should I use your method and not the class-method? Are there certain advantages in this method comparing to the other?

Comment: Classes will work fine as well. It depends on whether you want a `<b>` tag (probably better a `<strong>` tag nowadays), which is semantic, or a class, which is just style.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but you could buffer the contents:

```
$output .= "<td>";
$buffer = $value['from'];
$buffer = substr($value['message'], 20);
$output .= ('0' == $value['treated'])
    ? "<b>" . $buffer . "</b>"
    : $buffer;
```

Edit: I see deceze was first :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way you can acheive

```
$output .= '<td>';
        $bs = '';
        $be = '';
        if ('0' == $value['treated']) {
            $bs = '<b>';
            $be = '</b>';
        }
        $output .= $bs;
        $output .= $value['from'];
        $output .= substr($value['message'], 20);
        $output .= $be;
    $output .= '</td>';
```

or

```
$output .= '<td';
    if ('0' == $value['treated']) {
        $output .=' style="font-weight:bold;"';
    }
    $output .= '>';
    $output .= $value['from'];
    $output .= substr($value['message'], 20);
$output .= '</td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('<html/>');
$body = $dom->documentElement->appendChild($dom->createElement('body'));
for ( $i = 0; $i < 100; ++$i ) {
    $div = $body->appendChild($dom->createElement('div'));
    if ( rand() % 2 ) {
        $div->setAttribute('class', 'highlighted');
        $div->nodeValue = 'bold';
    } else {
        $div->nodeValue = 'normal';
    }
}
die($dom->saveHTML());
```